# How to Query one table based on the values of another table?

Tags: php, mysql

I have got 3 tables, "user", "message" "queue".

The **user** table consists of user id ("id") and status ("status").

[image: The "user" table]

The **message** table consists of user id ("id") and message ("msg").

[image: The "message" table]

The **queue** table is a copy of the **message** table.

[image: The "queue" table]

What my code does is simply copies the **message** table and pastes it to the **queue** table.

```
$query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO queue(id,msg) SELECT id,msg FROM message";
if ($DBcon->query($query)) {
    echo "Done";
} else {
    echo "Failed";
}
```

But I want to copy the row from message table to queue table only if the user's **status** is set to **"y"**.

Please help me with this. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use  a join and where

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO queue(id,msg) 
SELECT id,msg 
FROM message
INNER JOIN user on user.id = message.id
WHERE user.status  = 'Y';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
INSERT INTO queue (id, msg)
SELECT A.id, A.msg
FROM message A
JOIN users B
ON A.id=B.id
WHERE B.status= 'y';
```